# Updater function not working in variable context api - react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-native, react-context

Please help, I am creating a survey system. Each survey will have an undetermined number of questions, so their painting is done dynamically, that is, if it is type select, text, numeric, etc... for each one I render a different component. Now, I have created a ResponsesContext, a context to have the responses of the different modules or/or surveys globally, in such a way that when I leave a module and later return again, it loads the responses that the user already had filled out. .

In context I have the following code:

```
import React from "react";

const RespuestasContext = React.createContext();

//Provider
const RespuestasProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const [respuestas, setRespuestas] = React.useState({});

    const manejadorRespuestas = (modulo, codPregunta, respuesta) => {
        let tmp_respuestas = respuestas

        if (tmp_respuestas.hasOwnProperty(modulo)) {
            //Actualizar      
            if (tmp_respuestas[modulo].hasOwnProperty(codPregunta)) {
                tmp_respuestas[modulo][codPregunta] = {
                    respuesta
                }
            } else {
                insertar({ modulo, codPregunta, respuesta })
            }

        } else {
            //Insertar
            insertar({ modulo, codPregunta, respuesta })
        }
        setRespuestas(tmp_respuestas);

        return respuestas;
    }

    const insertar = (data) => {

        let tmp_respuestas = respuestas

        const { modulo, codPregunta, respuesta } = data

        if (tmp_respuestas.hasOwnProperty(modulo)) {
            tmp_respuestas[modulo][codPregunta] = {
                respuesta
            }
        } else {
            tmp_respuestas[modulo] = {
                [codPregunta]: {
                    respuesta
                }
            }
        }
        setRespuestas(tmp_respuestas);
    }

    const data = {
        respuestas,
        manejadorRespuestas     
    }

    return <RespuestasContext.Provider value={data}>{children}</RespuestasContext.Provider>;
}
export { RespuestasProvider };//themeProvider
export default RespuestasContext;//themecontext
```

In the component where I paint the form I have something like this:

```
const { respuestas, manejadorRespuestas } = useContext(RespuestasContext);

    renderQuestions = ({ item, index }) => {

        if (item.TIPO_CONTROL == 'text') {

            manejadorRespuestas(item.ID_MODULO, item.CODIGO, '')
            console.log('ping => ',respuestas[item.ID_MODULO][item.CODIGO].respuesta)

            return (
                <InputText
                    label={item.DESCRIPCION}
                    value={respuestas[item.ID_MODULO][item.CODIGO].respuesta}
                    onChange={(value) => {
                        manejadorRespuestas(item.ID_MODULO, item.CODIGO, value)
                        console.log('respuestas ', respuestas)
                    }}
                />
            )
        }
}
```

Every time the value of the input changes, the updater function updates the values in the responses variable of the context, but for some reason, when I access it in the value, like this: `value={respuestas[item.ID_MODULO][item.CODIGO].respuesta}` the change is not reflected, it simply deletes the field again, therefore the value in the context variable always has a letter that is the first character that I type in the input as seen in the console:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

If I want to write "Barrio el prado" for example, writing the first letter "B" calls the updater function... I don't know what could be causing this problem.

The "NOMBRE DEL BARRIO O VEREDA" field is question code 556 as seen in the console.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Thanks for your help.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJthz.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2aug.png

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, the updater function looked like this:

```
import React from "react";

const RespuestasContext = React.createContext();

//Provider
const RespuestasProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const [respuestas, setRespuestas] = React.useState({});

    const manejadorRespuestas = (modulo, codPregunta, respuesta) => {
        //let tmp_respuestas = respuestas

        if (respuestas.hasOwnProperty(modulo)) {
            //Actualizar      
            if (respuestas[modulo].hasOwnProperty(codPregunta)) {
                respuestas[modulo][codPregunta] = {
                    respuesta
                }
            } else {
                insertar({ modulo, codPregunta, respuesta })
            }

        } else {
            //Insertar
            insertar({ modulo, codPregunta, respuesta })
        }
        setRespuestas(respuestas);

        return respuestas;
    }

    const insertar = (data) => {

        let tmp_respuestas = respuestas

        const { modulo, codPregunta, respuesta } = data

        if (tmp_respuestas.hasOwnProperty(modulo)) {
            tmp_respuestas[modulo][codPregunta] = {
                respuesta
            }
        } else {
            tmp_respuestas[modulo] = {
                [codPregunta]: {
                    respuesta
                }
            }
        }
        setRespuestas(tmp_respuestas);
    }
    const obtenerRespuesta = (modulo, codPregunta) => {

        let respuesta = '';

        if (respuestas.hasOwnProperty(modulo)) {
            if (respuestas[modulo].hasOwnProperty(codPregunta)) {

                return respuestas[modulo][codPregunta].respuesta                
            } else {
                return respuesta
            }

        } else {
            return respuesta
        }

    }

    const data = {
        respuestas,
        manejadorRespuestas,
        obtenerRespuesta
    }

    return <RespuestasContext.Provider value={data}>{children}</RespuestasContext.Provider>;
}
export { RespuestasProvider };//themeProvider
export default RespuestasContext;//themecontext
```

I had to change in the TextInput from value to default Value:

```
<TextInput
     style={{ fontSize: 24 }}
     onChangeText={onChange}
     defaultValue={value}  
      placeholder={placeholder}                                             
/>
```

And in the TextInput component it looked like this:

```
<InputText
                label={`${item.DESCRIPCION} | ${item.CODIGO}`}
                value={obtenerRespuesta(item.ID_MODULO, item.CODIGO)}                    
                onChange={(value) => {                        
                    manejadorRespuestas(item.ID_MODULO, item.CODIGO, value) 
                }}
            />
```